# How to change teamd mac address?

Tags: linux, network-interface, bonding

I need to change mac address to two Ethernet cards which are teamed.Problem is that after changing the mac to my teammed interface or any of the two physical cards my ip connection get lost and i am not able to access the machine anymore.Please help me how to change mac address to teamed interface ???

```
 
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ctrl state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a3:44:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea3:4401/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ctrl state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a3:44:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea3:4401/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ctrl:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a3:44:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.23/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global ctrl
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea3:4401/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
teamdctl ctrl state
setup:
  runner: activebackup
ports:
  eth0
    link watches:
      link summary: up
      instance[link_watch_0]:
        name: ethtool
        link: up
        down count: 0
  eth1
    link watches:
      link summary: up
      instance[link_watch_0]:
        name: ethtool
        link: up
        down count: 0
runner:
  active port: eth0
```

I tried to change mac this way:

```
ip link set dev ctrl down
ip link set dev eth0 down
ip link set dev eth1 down
teamdctl ctrl port remove eth0
teamdctl ctrl port remove eth1
ip link set dev eth0 address 6C:2B:59:80:16:AE
ip link set dev eth1 address 6C:2B:59:80:26:AF
teamdctl ctrl port add eth0
teamdctl ctrl port add eth1
ip link set dev eth0 up
ip link set dev eth1 up
ifconfig ctrl up
```

Comment: If I would like to change hwaddr of an iface, I would do it via udev, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing#systemd-udevd, ie. before teamd would join the game. BTW, why your eth0 and eth1 show same hwaddr ?

Comment: @JiriB it's standard behaviour to set the same MAC for bonding/teaming in active-backup mode. So only the switch has to detect a failover, no layer 3 (including ARP) is involved.

Comment: The problem appeared only in virtualbox i have tried on physical server with centos and had no problem to change the mac.